# Use import-module with a PowerShell PSSnapin Dll

Tags: powershell, powershell-module, import-module, pssnapin

We have a legacy PowerShell PsSnapin (c#). I want to avoid having to use `InstallUtil`. The following imports a module with the PSSnapin cmdlets exported:

```
import-module .\MySnapin.dll
```

However, when I run the module cmdlets, they fail due to not being able to find referenced assemblies (specifically, Enterprise Library dlls).

Is there a neat way to get this working?

(The PsSnapin dll and all referenced assemblies are in the same build directory, and when I use installutil, the dependencies are all resolved correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Snap-ins are a bit different from Modules. You first need to register the snap-in, using [InstallUtil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
PS> $InstallUtil = Join-Path $([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()) "InstallUtil.exe"
PS> & $InstallUtil "C:\Path\to\MySnapin.dll"
```

After registering the snapin assembly, you can load it into your powershell session with `Add-PSSnapin`:

```
PS> Add-PSSnapIn MySnapin
```

Comment: indeed - that's what we usually do, but I was explicitly trying to avoid InstallUtil. E.g. so I can load two versions of the same snapin, etc.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I don't know if this is viable but: Rename one version, recompile, register both, shift between them with `Add/Remove-PSSnapIn` perhaps?